# writing strings to 2 decimal places in a cvs file

Tags: python, python-2.7, formatting

Can you help me to modify this code to writing out numbers to 2 decimal places in a cvs file?

```
outfile = open("numbers.csv", "a")

outfile.write(str(datetime.strftime(datetime.now(), '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')) + "," + str(number_1) + "," + str(number_2) + "," + str(number_3)+ "," + str(number_4) + "," + str(number_5) + "," + str(number_6) + "," + str(number_7) + "," + str(number_8) + "," + str(number_9) +"\n")
```

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Do you mean [`round()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#round)?

Comment: I would also recommend replacing all those `number_1`, `number_2`, etc. with a basic `list`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the [`round()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#round) function before writing to the csv ,the second parameter to the round function is the number of decimal places to round-off to.

Example -

```
>>> number_1 = 1.4412324
>>> number_2 = 1.54988312
>>> round(number_1,2)
1.44
>>> round(number_2,2)
1.55
```

In your case -

```
outfile = open("numbers.csv", "a")

outfile.write(str(datetime.strftime(datetime.now(), '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')) + "," + str(round(number_1, 2)) + "," + str(round(number_2, 2)) + "," + str(round(number_3, 2))+ "," + str(round(number_4, 2)) + "," + str(round(number_5, 2)) + "," + str(round(number_6, 2)) + "," + str(round(number_7, 2)) + "," + str(round(number_8, 2)) + "," + str(round(number_9, 2)) +"\n")
```

Answer (score 0):

You can consider using  `format`

```
"{:.2f}".format(24.45679)
```

gives you `'24.46'`.